# Derivation of the Euler-Lagrange equation in the isoperimetric case

Tags: calculus-of-variations

In [this](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/%7Eucahmto/latex_html/chapter2htlatex.html) derivation (and also [here](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.368.1522&rep=rep1&type=pdf)) of the Euler-Lagrange equation in the isoperimetric case, one begins with an extremising function $y$ and adds two terms, obtaining $\hat{y} = y + \epsilon_1 \eta_1 + \epsilon_2 \eta_2$, where $\epsilon_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\eta_i = \eta_i (x)$.  The summand $\epsilon_2 \eta_2$, which is not present in the unconstrained case, is a "correction term", included so that $\hat{y}$ satisfies the isoperimetric constraint, despite the perturbation of $y$ by $\epsilon_1 \eta_1$.

However, the subsequent calculation of $\frac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon_1}$ treats $\epsilon_2$ as being independent of $\epsilon_1$.  How can this be?  Is the derivation incorrect, or have I misunderstood?